# One Activity with two themes programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, styles, themes

I have a problem with switching activity theme programmatically. I have an router activity that decide which activity to route based on some condition. And that router activity can be open at two time : application start up time with Splash screen theme and calling startActivity from somewhere to make router decision with NoDisplay or Transparent theme. I've set splash theme in manifest and it works fine. But I can't change to transparent theme at runtime when calling startactivity. It shows black background color instead of transparent.

RouterActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val transparent = intent.extras?.getBoolean("Need_Transparent")?:false
    if(transparent) setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //no setContentView()
}
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".RouterActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So how can I make that RouterActivity with two themes: Splash (default in manifest) and Transparent theme (open with startActivity from other activity).

Comment: You can check this demo : https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultipleThemeMaterialDesign

Answer (score 3):

I am giving this solution in Java, Hopefully same logic should also work in Kotlin,

Best way to set theme is overriding the Resources Theme in your class and putting the same logic which is present in `OnCreate` method

```
@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
    if(useAlternativeTheme){
        theme.applyStyle(R.style.AlternativeTheme, true);
    }
      // you could also use a switch if you have many themes that could apply
    return theme;
}
```

Comment: The activity appear with black background color. I don't know why.

Comment: Oh, That's bad. For testing purpose could you change the color of transparent to something which is solid color? to check if the theme is getting set?

Comment: Using solid color works. But when I set transparent color, it just shows black bg color.

Comment: And also, when I apply transparent theme in manifest, it works. It seems like only programatic transparent theme not works.

Comment: That is because Transparent theme is getting applied on the solid theme, Hence you are not able to view that transparent theme, One thing what you can try is changing your logic to first make transparent theme apply and then change to solid when required